# Best fundamental literature about genetics

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, literature

I'm seeking for good genetics literature. I'm not afraid of it's complexity, because I want to have relevant knowledges about molecular genetics. After Wikipedia articles and basic molecular-biology books I need something, that can explain some aspects more detailed. I need something fundamental, but not abstract or scientifically popular. I understand, that question probably will be closed, but I don't know any other place to ask.

Comment: Finding something more fundamental and more detailed than Wikipedia might be a challenge.

Comment: For textbooks, I think Gene X is very detailed, very comprehensive.

Comment: "genetics" is extremely broad. Could you identify a specific discipline? e.g. molecular genetics/molecular biology, human population genetics, evolutionary genetics, genomics, plant genetics, developmental genetics, biotechnology...? The obvious answer would be "a genetics textbook" but I suspect you want something more specific.

Comment: @Maximilian Press Probably, molecular genetics is what i need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think of a few different sources that might be interesting to you, focusing specifically on so-called "Central Dogma" ideas.

My personal bias is I think that knowing a bit of the history is invaluable for understanding the concepts, because a lot of the concepts turn out to be tied up in how they were discovered. Most of the big-picture stuff in molecular biology was figured out by 1980 or so, and molecular genetics followed closely behind.

Matthew Cobb has written a number of good books about how famous discoveries were made- I've read [Life's Greatest Secret](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1781251401), which I found very readable and also informative about the discovery of the genetic code.

Sean Carroll wrote a [good book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endless_Forms_Most_Beautiful_(book)) about molecular mechanisms in developmental biology.

Both of these are "pop science" books but they are written by PhD biologists with a lot of technical details.

I am very fond of Erwin Chargaff's books as well but he is not to everyone's taste; he missed a few things early on in the history of molecular biology by being over-cautious, and was rather bitter about it later, which bled through in his writing. Most relevant probably are "Essays on Nucleic Acids" and "That Heraclitean Fire".

You could also read Jim Watson's book [Molecular Biology of the Gene](https://www.pearson.com/store/p/molecular-biology-of-the-gene/P100001320201/9780321762436), which is rather old (though updated) but is a lot better on the technical aspects than most textbooks by my understanding. (He's a bad person but the book is good.)

And of course MIT has [online molecular genetics courses](https://ocw.mit.edu/high-school/biology/exam-prep/molecular-genetics/).